# Warning default start runlevel arguments do not match Default-Start values

Tags: boot, services, runlevel

I tried to add [Fuseki](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/) as a service to the correct runlevels using `update-rc.d`. I used `sudo update-rc.d fuseki defaults` and I think is okay now, but I got this warnings:

```
update-rc.d: warning: default start runlevel arguments (2 3 4 5) do not match fuseki Default-Start values (3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:
default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match fuseki Default-Stop values (0 1 2 6)  
Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/fuseki ...
    /etc/rc0.d/K20fuseki -> ../init.d/fuseki
    /etc/rc1.d/K20fuseki -> ../init.d/fuseki
    /etc/rc6.d/K20fuseki -> ../init.d/fuseki
    /etc/rc2.d/S20fuseki -> ../init.d/fuseki
    /etc/rc3.d/S20fuseki -> ../init.d/fuseki
    /etc/rc4.d/S20fuseki -> ../init.d/fuseki
    /etc/rc5.d/S20fuseki -> ../init.d/fuseki
```

What exactly does this warning mean?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: can you post the lines  `# Default-Start:`  and  `# Default-Stop:` from /etc/init.d/fuseki ?

Comment: @muru Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64)

Comment: @LilloX # Default-Start:     3 4 5 
# Default-Stop:      0 2 1 6

Comment: as I had imagined,  see the answer I gave. Plus, the services is stopped at runlevel 2 because runlevel 2 is without network.

Comment: @LilloX What do you mean, runlevel 2 is without network? Runlevels 2, 3, 4 and 5 are equivalent on Ubuntu. If one of them doesn't have network, none of them have.

Comment: @muru yes correct. Differently from LSB ubuntu does not differentiate runlevels 2-5. The convention was runlevel 2: multiuser with no network services exported. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the manual update-rc.d:

```
If defaults is used then update-rc.d will make links to start the
service in runlevels 2345 and to stop the service in runlevels 016.
```

It seems that, instead, the runlevels defined in /etc/init.d/fuseki are: start runlevel 3,4 and 5 as stop 0,1 and 6. This is not the default and the program alerts you that.